# Meaning of 'Wasted'

Tags: meaning

I've just watched the Simpsons episode "Bart Gets a 'Z'" (LABF15).

During this episode Seymour Skinner reads the front page of a news paper called "Daily Fourth Gradian". On the front page there's a comment saying:

> "I KNOW WASTED-
>       AND THAT'S WASTED."

[image]

What does this mean? Is it a saying?

Comment: "wasted" means "to be very drunk". "I know wasted" means "I know (or can identify) when someone's very drunk". "And that's wasted" means "And that person is definitely very drunk".

Comment: Why don't you write an answer? :)

Comment: why exactly is this question upvoted, a simple google search answers it.

Comment: @V0ight Apparently other people find it to be a noteable expression or at least worth an explanation. I now understand that sentence, but still think it's grammatically exceptional. If you don't agree, downvote or flag as off topic. Besides: I am aware of the way SEs work and tried to look it up myself. I didn't find any satisfying results so I decided to ask this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In slang, ***wasted*** means "To be EXTREMELY intoxicated from the use of alcohol or drugs" ([Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wasted)).

The phrase ***I know wasted*** means "I can recognize when someone's very intoxicated." It can also mean "I am very familiar with the state of being very intoxicated."

These come from two ancillary definitions of ***know***:

> 2.2 Recognize (someone or something)
>
> 2.3 Be familiar or acquainted with (something) ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/know))

***I know wasted*** is kind of an idiomatic construction since the participle "wasted" is being used in a strange position. But the sentence is analogous to a sentence like "I know good art," meaning that the speaker can recognize good art because they are so familiar with it.

***And that's wasted*** means "And *that* person is definitely very intoxicated." When spoken, there would usually be a big emphasis on the word 'that'.

Finally, the structure ***I know ___, and that's ___*** is fairly common and mildly humorous:

- I know art, and *that*'s art!
- I know good movies, and *that*'s a good movie!
- I know science, and *that*'s science!

Comment: So in a way it's short for "I know _what it's like to be_ wasted"?

Comment: Yep. That's what the first line means. The next line ("and that's wasted") means "and *he/she* is definitely wasted."